# how to alternate multiple row colors in table when i know number of rows to color and table length in advance

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to alternate colors for multiple rows in a table. In advance i know the number of rows that i want to highlight, for example an array(8,8,9) tells me i want the first 8 rows one color and the next eight rows an alternating color and the last nine rows the first color again. he table length is 25 rows. My tables will change and my rows that i want colored can be array(4,4,5,5,5) for example. what is the best way of doing this in javascript or is there a jquery solution. I tried doing loops to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is enough to do this. No need of javascript and jQuery.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: blue;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: green;
}
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/d7FjX/)**

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants... Maybe his alternating pattern depdends on the data of the table, so static CSS is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
var arr = [8, 8, 9];

var $tr = $('table tr');
var index = 0;

$.each(arr, function(i, el) {
    index = i > 0 ? arr[i - 1] + index : 0;
    $tr.slice(index, index + el).addClass(i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');
});
```

The key is [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to apply styles to specified `tr` ranges.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39QvX/

Or another version using `for` loop:

```
for (var index = 0, i = 0; i < arr.length; index += arr[++i - 1] || 0) {
    $tr.slice(index, index + arr[i]).addClass(i % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd');
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/39QvX/2/

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. Quick additional question, is there any way I can skip the first 3 rows of the table and start coloring at row 4 (this would never change)?